# Husqvarna chainsaw will not idle but runs just fine

Tags: engine, chainsaw

I have a Husqvarna 435 (not `e` version) rancher and it's a great saw.  This is semi-related to home improvement I do see other posts like this here.

I have the spline tool and I can adjust the high idle just fine, but no matter where I put the `L` setting screw (all the way in or all the way out), the saw will not idle more than a second.  I can cut with it but have to constantly keep it revving a bit.

My question is, if the L screw is doing nothing, then would the next reasonable step be to replace the carb?  I've seen a video and it doesn't seem that hard but I wonder if there is an interim step I should try before that.  I have searched and see plenty of videos on how to tune a carb, but nothing when the L screw doesn't work.  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the associated jet/orifice for the L needle valve might be clogged. Cleaning or (if replaceable by itself) replacing that might be expected to help.

Comment: FWIW, you may get better help on the mechanics.stackexchange.com site. Small engine repair questions are on-topic there, in spite of the nominal "motor vehicle" charter of the site (see e.g. https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/are-small-engines-on-topic and https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234/would-the-community-welcome-questions-on-small-engine-repair-and-maintenance)

Comment: I've run both Huskys and Stihl chain saws and other landscaping equipment. On my Stihl tools I've gone thru a few carburetors and I always run non-ethanol gas, but often forget about fuel stabilizer. Still they get run most of the year here in western Washington (stuff grows here year around!), so less chance of gas going stale.  Carbs just wear out and they aren't very expensive for small engines.   I think the last one I bought for my Stihl motor head (uses various attachments) cost about $30. Installation was literally 2 screws to remove the old carb and install the new one.

Comment: I agree with George but would try some spray carb cleaner, you can replace everything on that saw for not much have done 2 or 3 pistons and cylinders this year. Many carb problems are fixed with cleaning but if not EBay is your friend, carbs are easy to change if you get a new one take that one apart and clean it, then you may have a spare for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many chain saws have two needle screws, one for the idle jet and one for the main jet.

There is a pretty good chance you have something blocking the flow for the idle.  It could be a particle of sawdust, or it could be gelled fuel which sat in the carburetor for a while.  This happens frequently with high ethanol fuel.

The good news is that by disassembling the carburetor, cleaning out any junk, and reassembling it, there is a high probability that you will get your chain saw running just fine.  The cost for the parts is typically $5 to $15.  The time it will take is 30 to 90 minutes.

Prior to high ethanol content in gasoline, this repair would be infrequent.  Now, it seems, some carburetors can clog  up after 3 months of not being used, with fuel in them.

Worst case, some people will buy a knock-off carburetor which might be $20 to $60.  However my guess is that you are savvy enough to replace gaskets and clean out the parts and pieces prior to reassembly.